# Istanbul code coverage. Ignore if without else

Tags: code-coverage, istanbul

I am doing code coverage of an app running live and need to ignore some guard conditions that never are covered when app is running live. I tried all options below and still have red flag near my if statement:

1: Ignore if and else in  one tag

```
/* istanbul ignore if|else */
if (A) {
      throw new Error("..null or undefined.");
}
```

2: Ignore if and else in two tags

```
/* istanbul ignore if */
/* istanbul ignore else */
if (A) {
      throw new Error("..null or undefined.");
}
```

3: Ignore else, then ignore code inside if with 'next':

```
/* istanbul ignore else */
if (A) {
      /* istanbul ignore next */
      throw new Error("..null or undefined.");
}
```

4: Ignore if:

```
/* istanbul ignore if */
if (A) {
      throw new Error("..null or undefined.");
}
```

5: Ignore with multiple next's:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
if (A) {
      /* istanbul ignore next */
      throw new Error("..null or undefined.");
}
```